# Hide block on specific page through custom contextual link

Tags: navigation, blocks

We usually require to hide some blocks on specific pages for which we need to goto configure block page and add the URL of the page where we do not want to display a block.

Instead of going to configure block page, I want to add a contextual link " Don't display on this page"

which should add the path of the current page in the list on which the block should not appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [context module](http://drupal.org/project/context) which has good number of contextual filters that can be used dynamically to display/hide a block.

> Context allows you to manage contextual conditions and reactions for
>   different portions of your site. You can think of each context as
>   representing a "section" of your site. For each context, you can
>   choose the conditions that trigger this context to be active and
>   choose different aspects of Drupal that should react to this active
>   context.